# Java calling of classes simultaneously

Tags: java, stack-overflow

There are two java classes both having main function. Now i have to call object of first class to the second and object of second class to first. Whenever i m doing this it is giving stack overflow exception. Is there any way to call these simulatneously?

First class :

```
 public class ChangePasswordLogin extends javax.swing.JFrame { 
     Connection con = null; 
     Statement stmt = null; 
     ResultSet rs = null; 
     String message = null; 
     RandomStringGenerator rsg = new RandomStringGenerator(); 
     MD5Generator pass = new MD5Generator(); 
     PopUp popobj = new PopUp();
     ForgotPassword fpemail = new ForgotPassword();
```

Second class:

```
public class ForgotPassword extends javax.swing.JFrame { 
    Connection con = null; 
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String message = null; 
    String useremail; 
    PopUp popobj = new PopUp(); 
    RandomStringGenerator rsg = new RandomStringGenerator(); 
    MD5Generator pass = new MD5Generator(); 
    ChangePasswordLogin cpl = new ChangePasswordLogin();
```

Comment: what do you mean by this - *two java classes both having main function.*

Comment: Please [edit] the code into your question. Don't post unformatted code in the comments.

Comment: This has nothing to do with both having a main function. They're creating new objects of each other recursively.

Comment: @JatinDogra - Post code that *compiles*.

Comment: And again, don't post the code in the comments. Edit it into your question so it can be properly formatted....

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - I was merely trying to understand what he meant by that. I know it is unrelated to StackOverflowError. :)

Comment: So any solution to this #hovercraft.full.of.eels

Comment: See answer. Use setter methods.

Comment: Sorry fellas new to stackoverflow. By the way thanks Hovercraft.

Answer (score 5):

You've got recursion going on where class A creates an instance of class B in its constructor and class B creates an instance of A in its constructor or initiation code. This will continue on and on until you run out of memory. The solution is not to do this. Use setter methods to set the instances outside of the constructor and initiation code.

This can be demonstrated simply with:

```
// this will cause a StackOverfowException
public class RecursionEg {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      A a = new A();
   }
}

class A {
   private B b = new B();
}

class B {
   private A a = new A();
}
```

Solved with setter methods:

```
// this won't cause a StackOverfowException
public class RecursionEg {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      A a = new A();
      B b = new B();
      a.setB(b);
      b.setA(a);
   }
}

class A {
   private B b;

   public void setB(B b) {
      this.b = b;
   }
}

class B {
   private A a;

   public void setA(A a) {
      this.a = a;
   }
}
```

Substitute ForgotPassword and ChangePasswordLoging for A and B.

Or you could get by like the code below, where you take care to create one instance of each type:

```
public class RecursionEg {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      A a = new A();
   }
}

class A {
   private B b = new B(this);   
}

class B {
   private A a;

   public B(A a) {
      this.a = a;
   }

   public void setA(A a) {
      this.a = a;
   }
}
```

Comment: @JatinDogra: see edit to answer. Thanks for editing your question and adding code. In the future, you'll want to post pertinent code from the get go.

Comment: I would like to ask we have to make another class for stopping recursion

Comment: @JatinDogra: no, there is no need to make another class. The main method can go anywhere.